# OpenShift - no awt in java.library.path

Tags: awt, openshift

I use `Openshift` for a small app.
In this app, I upload images and resize them and stores them in a database.
I use: `BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(inputStream);`

But today when I run this part of code I got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in java.library.path
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1657)
```

...

I do not know if the `OpenShift` team has done any upgrade lately. Last time I run that code was perhaps 6 months ago.

Do you guys have any solution?

Best regards
Fredrik

Answer (score 0):

A rebuild, a redeploy and a restart solved the problem.
Really strange.

To me this sounds like a system thing and would not have to do with the app itself.

Best regards
Fredrik